# iOS 7.1 Default tint color does not change for UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch, tintcolor

I've set default tint color in my storyboard, but I'm getting old blue, default color for my UISwitch component.

So I've tried to put

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:APPCOLOR];
```

inside of my app delegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

but still no luck, I also tried to put there

```
[[UISwitch appearance] setTintColor:APPCOLOR];
```

and again no change.

The `APPCOLOR` is defined in my constants.h file which I of course include.

**How I can set this tint color of my UISwitch globally?**

The tint color of other elements, for example UIButton changes properly.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `UISwitch` tint color controls the border color. If you want to set the on color, you need to use `onTintColor`.

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISwitch.html) the documentation of what these tint colors represent for `UISwitch`.

[image]

Also, you should not be setting appearance in `applicationWillResignActive:` delegate method.  This is called when the application resigns active state. You should set appearance in `application:didLaunchWithOptions:`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.